# Why does this background color not go over my image?

Tags: html, css, image, background, z-index

I need this kindof pink-ish glow over my picture. This is my code right now... Does anyone have a solution for this? The glow needs to be over my image, not under it as it is right now.

```css
.afbeelding img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #a81932;
}

.paarsegloed {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(168, 25, 50, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="paarsegloed">
<div class="afbeelding">
<img src="https://www.buromac.com/sites/default/files/public/images/product/be-nl/650901_1.jpg" style="">
</div>
</div>
```

Dont bother about the size of the picture, Thats just as an example. I just need to get this background color over the picture, Not under it as it is right now.

Kind regards,
Jorn Barkhof

Comment: A background is a _background_, you can not make that show _in front of_ descendant elements. You need to position the element that contains the background over the image to begin with, meaning they can’t be nested like that.

Comment: I've used it like this before, Usually in the CMS i work in it is possible like this, Use a background over the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current html, you can't. Try this

```css
.afbeelding img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #a81932;
}

.afbeelding:before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(168, 25, 50, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="paarsegloed">
  <div class="afbeelding">
    <img src="https://www.buromac.com/sites/default/files/public/images/product/be-nl/650901_1.jpg" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is move paarsegloed inside afbeelding, then using absolute position, but this seems not really a background of afbeelding.

```css
.afbeelding img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #a81932;
    float: left;
}

.paarsegloed {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(168, 25, 50, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
   
<div class="afbeelding">
<img src="https://www.buromac.com/sites/default/files/public/images/product/be-nl/650901_1.jpg" style="">
<div class="paarsegloed">
</div>
</div>
```